# WCF App recieving multiple requests per second causing other asp.net apps to stop responding and deadlock

Tags: wcf, deadlock

We have a WCF Service using a wsHttpBinding.  When it recieves many requests in a short period of time (25 per second for a few minutes) it stops working and our other asp.net applications and pages to stop responding as well.  Some of them timeout and eventually we see the following in the event viewer:

ISAPI 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll' reported itself as unhealthy for the following reason: 'Deadlock detected'.

Often we get calls about the problem first and restart IIS to solve the problem.

How can we configure our WCF service to handle this many transmissions or at least configure it to not take down our other applications when it can't handle the load.  Our classic asp applications run without issues during this time, it's only our .net apps that are effected.

Answer (score 0):

are you running all your asp/wcf sites in the same AppPool? if so, I'd suggest creating a new one and running the WCF service just in that. That in itself might be enough to solve the problem from a practical perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Everything is running under it's own app pools so I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: This worked, we haven't had a problem since I created app pools for each of our apps.  Thanks!

Comment: Kristina--click the checkbox next to the answer if you want to accept it. This is how people on StackOverflow know that you accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also can you target a more recent version of the framework with your WCF app? (and leave the other apps the same) It will isolate it much better.